# MySqlException: Table 'dbname.AspNetUsers' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mariadb

I'm using asp.net MVC with mysql database. I have `MySql.Data v8.0.16.0` and `MySql.Data.EntityFramework v8.0.16.0`  installed.

Mysql provider added in web.config:

```
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
      </provider>
```

I'm using asp.net Idnetity. Here is the configuration:

```
 [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.EntityFramework.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
        public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
        {
            public ApplicationDbContext()
                : base("DefaultConnection")
            {
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("aspnetusers");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("aspnetroles");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("aspnetuserroles");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("aspnetuserclaims");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("aspnetuserlogins");

                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            }
    }
```

On my local pc, everything works fine, but on hosting server i get error, here is the complete exception with stack trace:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Table 'live-db-373103e4.AspNetUsers' doesn't exist at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.d__c.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.d__c.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.d__0`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.d__3d`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.d__e.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsyncEnumerator`1.d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.d__25`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.d__67.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) at Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject.Controllers.AccountController.d__7.MoveNext() in C:\Users\mirfa\source\repos\dealkar-refactored-2019\Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 139 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.b__0() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.b__2() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.b__4() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c.b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c.b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c.b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

server db version is: `10.1.35-MariaDB`.

these tables exist on server:
[image]

How can I solve the exception of table does not exist?

**Update:**

The code first migration is creating table name in upper case.i.e, `AspNetUsers` instead of `aspnetusers`. Shouldn't it create tables with lower case?

```
public partial class added_aspnetusers : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
             CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetUsers",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128, storeType: "nvarchar"),
                        status = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        //other columns
                    });
        }
    }
```

**Update:2**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassName>().ToTable("table_name");
```

entity framework is not changing name of table for any entity.

Comment: Looks like a case of case sensitivity. Why does the query in question use `AspNetUsers`, while you specify the table name in lower case?

Comment: I'm not using native sql queries, I'm using entity framework

Comment: there should be kind of version issue because same code is working fine in my visual studio

Comment: No, it's not a version issue. Your development PC runs Windows, and the server runs Linux, the latter having a case-sensitive MySQL installation. Either change that setting, or make sure all your code uses the same casing. It should work given your OnModelCreating. Which DbContext class does your AuthorizeController use?

Comment: I have single db context throughout the application mentioned in question.

Comment: Can't change the mysql settings because hosting provider don't allow. Could not figure out a way to fix in code.

Comment: @CodeCaster I found a clue, migration is not generating table in lower case, please check updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)` after customizing your table names.

That method configures the Identity table names, overwriting yours.

Move that line to the top of your overridden method.

Comment: still not working, i find out that entity framework .toTable() is not working, please see updated question.

Comment: It does work if you move `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)` so it's before your code. This of course doesn't affect already existing databases and migrations

Comment: In my case, I was re-scaffolding existing migration, I had to use `-Force`.